How can I replace NA values with 0 in specific columns?
I'm working with a large data set that has 3 columns with NA values, I need to replace the NA values in 2 of the columns with 0 but leave the third as NA to omit those rows in the third column that have NA as their value. I need to omit the NAs in only one column because I'm using that data for a distribution plot and the NA values are messing up the axis scaling.
I've replaced the column names I'm actually using with keep_NA, replace_NA1, and replace_NA2 in this code for clarity. The columns I need to replace are of type int and the keep is type num.
I've tried referencing the columns using na.omit():
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
d <- read.csv(...)
d_clean <- na.omit(d$omit_NA)

This produced a d_clean that omits all rows with NA values in all columns. I've also tried it this way:
d_clean <- d %>%
    mutate(na.omit(d$omit_NA))

which produced the same d_clean as the first code block. Then I tried replacing the NAs in the d_clean data frame before using na.omit() after copying the data like so:
d_clean <- d
d_clean[is.na(d_clean$replace_NA1)] <- 0
d_clean[is.na(d_clean$replace_NA2)] <- 0
na.omit(d_clean)

which did not replace or omit any of the NA values giving me a d_clean that was the same as d and gave this error:

Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, is.na(d_clean$replace_NA1), value = 0) :
duplicate subscripts for columns

I know that this is because I used d_clean$ but when I try it without calling the data frame it says the object cannot be found. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Welcome to SO.  If you're open to a tidyverse solution, d_clean <- d %>% replace_na(list(replace_NA1 = 0, replace_NA2 = 0)) should be close to what you want.  By the way, in the future, if you can't show your actual data, you can always make up some test data that demonstrates the problem.  Help yourself by helping us to help you.

d_clean[is.na(d_clean$replace_NA1)] <- 0 doesn't work because you need to tell it the rows and columns to replace, e.g., d_clean[is.na(d_clean$replace_NA1), "replace_NA1"] <- 0. You have data[rows] <- 0 but you need data[rows, column] <- 0. Alternatively, you could do data$column[rows] <- 0, so d_clean$replace_NA1[is.na(d_clean$replace_NA1)] <- 0. But these examples just show why a tidyverse solution is nicer.

Create an index on the two column sub-df and use it to assign zeros to NA's.
# repl can be 2:3 or
repl <- c("replace_NA1", "replace_NA2")
df1[repl] |> is.na() -> i
df1[repl][i] <- 0L

Created on 2024-11-05 with reprex v2.1.1
Or, assuming the columns vector is already created, in one code line.
repl <- c("replace_NA1", "replace_NA2")
df1[repl][ is.na(df1[repl]) ] <- 0L

Created on 2024-11-05 with reprex v2.1.1

Test data
df1 <- matrix(1:60, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("keep_NA", "replace_NA1", "replace_NA2")))
is.na(df1) <- sample(60, 20)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)

Created on 2024-11-05 with reprex v2.1.1
